How do I add a flag/image to the right of bars in pyplot
This is my code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.axes[0]
ax.barh(bar_y_corodinates_list, bar_lengths_list, tick_label=countries_list)

This is where I want to add a flag ie a small image

Just like I am passing a list of countries for Y-axis labels similarly
I want to pass a list of path of flag images from my disc.
I couldn't find any out of the box option to do in docs .
Is it possible ?
